# can aws parameter store programatically push changes to the clients?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-ssm

can aws parameter store programatically push changes to the clients?

once the configuration value is changed in aws parameter store, how do we ensure all the clients are now using the latest configuration value?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: [Setting Up Notifications and Events for Systems Manager Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-cwe.html). Maybe you can have your applications listen to an SNS notification?

I have services configured to use the latest credentials so when they restart they pick up new ones. When all services have restarted I invalidate the old credentials in whatever system they were for.
I do this in a manual fashion, but using SNS to restart could work for me.